# MySQL updating row number

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to copy calculated column values into the correct column of my table but when trying a second update, it doesn't recognize the calculated field.

This is my select:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 Rank, p.* 
from Poule p, 
    (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
WHERE p.Activity LIKE 'BallgameOne' 
order by TotalPoints desc
```

This results in a table with the rownumber (`rank`) and all columns of the Poule table. One of those columns in the `Poule` table is called `Position`.

I would like to copy the values of column `Rank` into column `Position`. Because the position got lost on an update. So I would like to do an update based on the returned select.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Does the `Poule` table have a primary key?

Comment: Yes, it is called 'Id'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table with the query that returns the ranks.

```
UPDATE Poule AS p1
JOIN (select @rownum:=@rownum+1 Rank, p.id
        from Poule p, 
            (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
        WHERE p.Activity LIKE 'BallgameOne' 
        order by TotalPoints desc) AS p2
ON p1.id = p2.id
SET p1.Position = p2.Rank
```